# Set Product Images with URLs of a product programmatically

Tags: php, image, magento, frontend

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I am planing to create a product programmatically from frontend every thing is working fine that images also ..

But now i want to set images programmatically for this just i am getting the image Urls of one product thats exist in my magento

```
<?php $_xproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(10)->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
      <?php if($_xproduct) {  ?>
          <?php $i=0;       
    foreach($_xproduct as $_image) { 
               $i++; 
            ?>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_image->getFile(); ?>" />
<?php } } ?>
```

Here inside text box i am getting all images Urls. Now i want to store that Images as my product Images

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456954/magento-programmatically-add-product-image