# steps to import images with a product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What are the steps to import a product with images. I mean - the images, precisely.
So I have this code now:

```
protected function _getImages($product)
{
            $importImagesDirectory = Mage::getBaseDir()."/".Mage::getStoreConfig('xmlimport/product/import_images_dir');
            if(file_exists($importImagesDirectory))
            {
                $addImage['sku'] = (string)$product['PK_Produkt'];
                $addImage['_media_image'] = $importImagesDirectory . $this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"');
                $addImage['_media_attribute_id'] = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
                $addImage['_media_is_disabled'] = 0;
                $addImage['_media_position'] = 1;
// the following 4 lines are just acquiring string values - the name of the picture
                $addImage['_media_lable'] = $this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"');
                $addImage['image'] = $this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"');;
                $addImage['small_image'] = $this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"');;
                $addImage['thumbnail'] = $this->_getPresentationAttributeValue($product, '@Art="Bild" and @Rang="1"');;

            }
            else Mage::log('Error! Image with name: ' . $importImagesDirectory . ' does not exist! ', null, 'error_image.log', true);

            return $addImage;
}
```

So this array is being merged with the array containing the product information, that is being imported. Now, I was said that the function should also move the images from my `media/import/` folder to somewhere `catalog/product/` folder, because Magento looks up for images in that folder. Anf if I just import the information, but don't move the images - then no effect (which actually happens right now).

So I am asking, how does that work, is there a function from the API to make this "movement", is that the correct procedure?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456954/magento-programmatically-add-product-image).

Comment: @MihaiStancu - Oh, I think I understand. So `$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';` is the directory where the images should be moved to (where Magento looks for images). And `addImageToGallery()` is the function that actually places the images there. Is that correct?
Then arises the problem, that I cannot call `addImageToGallery()` on my `$product` variable, because it is of `SimpleXMLElement` type and I get the `call on non-object` error... :\

Comment: You need to create an new `$product` object. In Magento that should be easy `$new_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` and then you need to load its data from the DB for example `$new_product->load($id); /* not sku */`. `addImageToGallery` should work fine on a `catalog/product` object.

Comment: @MihaiStancu - but with `Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';` I get the same directory as my `$importImagesDirectory`. Don't I need the directory where the images should be moved TO? Or the `addImageToMediaGallery()` finds the folder and does that by itself. Because I looked through its code and it doesn't seem to do that...

Comment: Magento stores stuff in `media/catalog/product/X/Y/XYfilename.ext` where X and Y are the first letters of the filename. So Magento creates two levels of subfolders based on the first two letters in the filename. This logic is not present directly in `addImageToMediaGallery` but afaik it is in the lower levels of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456954/magento-programmatically-add-product-image) answer you need to use `addImageToMediaGallery`.

You need to have an instance of a `catalog/product` object. That should be easy `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` and then you need to load its data from the DB for example `$product->load($id);`.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
```

Magento stores product files in `media/catalog/product/X/Y/XYfilename.ext` where `X` and `Y` are the first letters of the filename. So Magento creates two levels of subfolders based on the first two letters in the filename. This logic is not present directly in `addImageToMediaGallery`, it's in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage()`.

magento_root: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php